# Time series chart CHIRPS data in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, chart

I am trying to derive a time series chart of the CHIRPS daily data set (precipitation) at a specific location. However, I get the following error "Error generating chart: No properties to chart."
Alternatively, it would work for me also to export the daily values in a table for the required time frame.
Please see below the script.

```
var lng = 69.78086; 
var lat = 34.65411;
var point = ee.Geometry.Point(lat, lng).buffer(30); 

var country = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'AF'));
var aoi = country;

Map.setCenter(lng,lat, 5); // Center the map on this location, zoom level 10

var start = '2018-02-15'; // initial date of the image collection
var end = '2018-07-15'; //final date of the image collection

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
    .filterDate(start, end)
    .filterBounds(aoi);
    
print(ui.Chart.image.series(dataset, point, ee.Reducer.first(), 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to define your `ee.Geometry.Point()` as:

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([lng, lat])
```